# Dash.js only working with their sample video path

Tags: dash.js

I was following the instructions in the dash.js docs:
http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/index.html#toc3__anchor

it works all fine with their sample video src: dash.edgesuite.net/envivio/EnvivioDash3/manifest.mpd

the next step in the docs is: "Switch out the manifest URL to your own manifest once you have everything working"

that is what i do but as soon as I use my own video src it is not working anymore instead the browser donwloads the entire video with 180MB all at once. The convertion to dash.js takes place though:

[9] EME detected on this user agent! (ProtectionModel_21Jan2015)

Debug.js:108[16] Playback Initialized

Debug.js:108[27] [dash.js 2.3.0] MediaPlayer has been initialized

Debug.js:108[27] Converted main_video to dash.js player and added content: http://mywebsite.com/myvideo.mp4

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dash.js player can only play MPEG DASH content. You are trying to play a progressive MP4 file - http://mywebsite.com/myvideo.mp4 - which is not a MPEG DASH file. You need to package this file to DASH first, using a solution such as mp4box or bento.

https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/dash/

https://bitmovin.com/mp4box-dash-content-generation-x264/

https://www.bento4.com/developers/dash/

Cheers
Will